# I've just bought a new Soldering Iron with the intent of making Art, however I seem to have a problem

Tags: soldering

I bought this: [http://www.amazon.com/Weller-SP40NKUS-Medium-Soldering-Black/dp/B00B3SG7F0/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1394083021&sr=8-2&keywords=weller+soldering+iron](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B3SG7F0)

The other day so that I can solder together vintage watch pieces into figurines (and yes, I know for sure this is a good way to go about making these), but before my watch pieces came in I wanted to play around with the iron to see what it could do, since I've never soldered before in my life. I've watched some videos of people soldering, but I'm a bit confused as to what I've done to mine. I turned it on, let it heat up, and then touched the tip to the lead-free solder that came with it. Immediately the solder melted onto the tip (Which I'm assuming is called tinning? And I understand that this is a good thing), but when I tried to wipe the solder off the tip, it didn't seem to come off. Once it dried, my tip appeared dark matte grey, and now even a little orange-ish near the base of the tip. 
Can someone maybe shed some light on what I've done? I'm not sure if i've just rusted my new tip or not.

Comment: Did you try heating it up again?

Comment: Yes, I heated it up again to see if solder would 'wet' to it again, but now whenever I try to touch solder to the tip it wont adhere at all. It beads up and falls off.

Comment: Time to get some flux then.

Comment: Why? Again, brand new to this, so I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: The surface of the tip and solder have oxidized. Flux is a powerful reducing agent. This will help further solder wet, and may help loosen the existing solder.

Comment: Where should I apply flux to try and solve the problem?

Comment: To the surfaces that have oxidized.

Comment: One thing that helped me in such situation was to wind a coil of solder wire around the working part of the tip itself while the iron is cold and then turn it on. If you're lucky enough, the flux in the solder will melt right before the solder melts, so it should clean the tip. This helps, if you don't have separate flux at the moment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about art.

Comment: While this would *seem* on topic because it involves a soldering iron, people here have about zero experience soldering things that aren't electronics. This is like asking a chef how to sweat copper pipes, because chefs also use gas torches.

Comment: If there was a better place to post this please point me in the right direction. I could just have easily lied about what I was soldering and it would be on topic.

Comment: The tip might need filing off.  I don't understand why the desire for lead-free solder.  Flux is always a good idea, but please allow me to suggest Tip Tinner: 
  http://www.ebay.com/itm/Techspray-Plato-TT-95-Soldering-Iron-Tip-Tinner-Lead-Free-ESD-Safe-No-Residue-/261932321916

Answer (score 3):

Just as a point of order, soldering irons for art can be fairly different than irons for electronics.  You generally need much higher power as you're heating something much more massive than a tiny little lead or SMT pad.  Unless your parts are *truly tiny*, get an iron for stained glass.

Also, you likely *require* some additional flux to put on your work. Electronics parts are generally very clean and plated to aid solder wetting. Looking up some guides on stained glass soldering would be extremely useful, namely how they flux everything.

Finally, if you're trying to assemble something out of this and that by soldering, remember that not every metal is wettable with tin or tin-lead solder.